# Visual Studio C++ - Resource View blank?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, resources

I have a Visual Studio 2010 C++ project which was copied from another visual studio project and renamed.  The project compiles fine and works.  However recently, I went to the Resource View to edit some dialogs and the window is completely empty.  I can't remember if I went there since I copied the project or not:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can get this back?  I'm thinking there is some cache somewhere?

**UPDATE**

I should add that this solution is a multi-project solution and normally in the resource view even if a given project does not have resource files you will still see a "folder" for the project in the resource view tree view.  There are no "folders" for any of the projects in the solution.

I should also add that other solutions that I open in visual studio will display the resource view fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had similar problem that I solved with reloading projects in the solution (unload projects and then reload all projects).

Comment: The problem came back for me with my solution and I just tried your solution and it works thanks. I right clicked on each project in my solution and clicked "Unload Project". Then I came back and clicked "Reload Project" for each project. I like this better than creating a temp project

Comment: You can re-load all project at once - just right click on 'Solution' in solution explorer and then 'Unload Projects'. In the same place you can click on "Reload all projects'.

Answer (score 24):

It might be because your Browsing/Navigation Database is disabled.

Check the current setting under:
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C++ -> Advanced. "Disable Database" should be false.

This is a bug as far as I know, and they said they are working on the problem.

More Info:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535971/solution-resource-view-empty-when-option-disable-database-c-is-set-to-true

Comment: Thanks but this was already set to false.  I did try however setting it to true and restarting visual studio and then setting it back to false but this did nothing.

Comment: Still not corrected in VS2012, and we are 3 month before entering 2014, 4 years after the bug have been reported. They are working on it means they don't care. Visual Studio was the best IDE IMO, but sadly as the rule of 'Software bloat' predicts, it has became a bloatware (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bloat)

Comment: I had disabled the database on purpose to try and speed things up. I didn't realise it would mean that the resource view wouldn't work! I've enabled and reloaded all projects and it is all good.

Comment: I had to close and reopen visual studio 2012 for the resource view to repopulate after changing the "Disable Database" setting mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today, and my class browser was also empty. I fixed it by deleting the ipch directory and the sdf file from the solution's directory. Visual Studio reinitialized the intellisense databases, and the view were back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the .rc file in your `Solution Explorer`, then double-click it which should reload it in the `Resource View`.

Also check to make sure the `.vcxproj` file is referencing the correct .rc file (open it up in a text editor). Perhaps you renamed it or something.

Comment: Tried double clicking on the .rc file in my project and it does take me to the resource view but the view is blank as I show in my question.  Also did look in the .vcxproj file but the .rc file names referenced are the correct file names.

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo! Figured it out.  Since each project normally has a entry on the Resource View tab regardless of whether it has resources or not, I decided to add a new temp project to my solution to see how visual studio would handle that.  So I right clicked on my solution and clicked Add->New project.. and added a new Win32 project with the setting of static library and MFC checked.  Once I added the project and went to the resource view all my other projects were back!  Then I just deleted the temp project I created.

I'm not sure what it did, but it must have forced visual studio to rebuild some internal cache or something.

Comment: This worked however the problem came back again next time I reopened the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem: Resource View was totally blank for a solution with several projects.

I had moved the entire file heirarchy's top directory to a different place (different disk mount too) which probably had something to do with it.

After I finally got all the paths changed (files in projects, the the projects' include and lib paths and so on) and started back on developing, I noted the Resource View was empty, and clicking on the .rc file didn't make anything visible.

But, saving the solution and restarting did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Simply closing & re-opening the Solution worked for me (VS 2017).

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused when forcing VS2010 to write browsing information to a location which doesn't exist. For example when settings are exported on another machine and then imported on a new machine which doesn't have this path.

In the following sample, I was forcing browsing information to be written to my local temp folder. When I imported my settings from an old computer, the path was pointing to a non-existent path.
[image: Example of a non-existent path imported from an installation on another machine.]